# No more (easily accessible) FAQ link?

Tags: feature-request, site-faq

I can't find the FAQ link on SO, where it used to be. Now it may have been moved or something but the fact that I have to look for it disturbs me. I was going to point the OP of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17344461/1530938) to the FAQ and I was left scrambling for the link. What gives?

Comment: Point to [help] instead, would work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no FAQ anymore, it's the help center now. (If you go to https://stackoverflow.com/faq you will be redirected to the help center.)

Also, you can just type `[help]` in the comments and it will automagically link to the help center. You can see an example in the comments below.

Comment: Type `[help]` and get [help]

Comment: Ah. Now I know. But isn't the "FAQ" title more traditional? As in first timers (and somewhat older hands) would be looking out for an FAQ link?

Comment: @kolossus generally it's now advisable to send folks to either specific pages of the help center for their specific issue or to the `[about]` page

Comment: @kolossus I guess that's just a matter of opinion, and the SE team apparently thought "help center" was a better name.

Comment: You can also type `[FAQ]` in a comment to get a link like this: [FAQ]

Comment: Yes, there's `[help]` [help], `[FAQ]` [FAQ], `[ask]` [ask], `[answer]` [answer], `[about]` [about], etc.

Comment: @Doorknob, thanks. You sure know your [FAQ]-isms. Hey, it works!